# Why my video won't render? - .blend file included

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am just trying to put together a video with its audio, and an additional audio (me talking).
I used a Speed Control Effect Strip on the video.
I had successfully rendered video before with the same settings. The only difference now is the additional audio strip.

I have tried both Eevee and Cycles with the following settings:

1. File Format: FFmpeg video, Encoding/Container: Mpeg-4, Video codec: H.264
2. File Format: FFmpeg video, Encoding/Container: QuickT, Video codec: FFmpeg video codec #1

[image]

P.S. Both the video and the audio file are not the actual files I am intending to use, this way they can be way smaller, while it should make no difference towards the rendering settings needed.

Comment: I don't see any video strip in the sequencer

Comment: Strange. You don't see this: 
http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=82d4806529dec1c1ae771d36b5b3f5c6

Comment: Please pack all external data and save the blend file before uploading.Check this image to see how. i.stack.imgur.com/7MbCb.png

Comment: Thanks Teja. I had done that and more. This time I downgraded to 2.79
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51244

Comment: Do not use external links to upload a .blend file. Use this one: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: LeoNas - Ok. Here it is, as provided: 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5899" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5899/)

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/d/5899/vrt-279.blend

Comment: I guess this became too long for anyone to want to help :( ...

Comment: I was having the same problem, so it said something at the bottom about an error with fps, so where it says in video settings your fps, just press that and press 30 fps again.